# Some questions about TestComplete

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcomplete

1. Which language is better for complex programming and exception handling?
2. What is the purpose of using aliases when object mapping is already done?
3. Can I highlight objects when tests are running?

Answer (score 0):

1. JScript or Python. These languages are the most powerful among the languages supported by TestComplete at the moment.
2. They allow you to build a custom object tree that you can use in your tests. This custom tree does not have to be similar to the actual object tree. If the actual object tree gets changed due to changes in the tested application GUI, you can update the Name Mapping tree without changing the Aliases tree and, therefore, without modifying any existing tests that use this custom Aliases tree.
3. Yes, use the [Sys.HighlightObject](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/74921/) method for this.

Comment: The docs moved: https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/test-objects/members/common-for-sys-desktop-pda/highlightobject-method-sys-pda-object.html